# Not getting solution for Error : No Adapter Attached Skipping Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i know its a duplicate question for so many fellows but i have tried all possible solutions which were given by community members but none of them helped me so i am posting this question as i am stuck with this error.I urge all the members please look at my code before marking it as duplicate.

i am using the recyclerview inside a fragment.

this is my fragment class:-

```
public class BuyOrders extends Fragment {

    private Boolean isConnected = true;
    private Socket mSocket;
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<BuyOrderHistory> mMessages = new ArrayList<BuyOrderHistory>();
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "BuyOrderHistoryFragment";

    public BuyOrders() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mAdapter = new BuyOrderHistoryAdapter(mMessages, context);
        if (context instanceof Activity) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        AppController app = (AppController) getActivity().getApplication();
        mSocket = app.getSocket();
        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on("connection_successfull", onConnect);
        mSocket.on("buy_orders_data", onBuyOrdersData);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_buyorders, container, false);
        return v;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
        mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        mSocket.off("connection_successfull", onConnect);
        mSocket.off("buy_orders_data", onBuyOrdersData);

        mSocket.disconnect();
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLinearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_buyorder);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }

    private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!isConnected) {


                        JSONObject data = (JSONObject)args[0];
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(data));

                        mSocket.emit("fetch_buy_orders",sendFetchBuyOrderRequest(""));
                        Log.i(TAG, "connected");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.string.connect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        isConnected = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    protected String sendFetchBuyOrderRequest(String s) {

        String pageno = "1";
        String recordperpage = "10";
        String userid = "22";

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("page_no:", pageno );
            jsonObject.put("records_per_page", recordperpage);
            jsonObject.put("user_id:", userid);

            return jsonObject.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       return s;

    }


    private Emitter.Listener onBuyOrdersData = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    Log.v("Data Coming From Server", String.valueOf(data));
                    String volume;
                    String bid;
                    String total;

                    try {
                        volume = data.getString("volume");
                        bid = data.getString("bid");
                        total = data.getString("total");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        return;
                    }

                    addData(volume,bid,total);

                }
            });
        }
    };


     protected void addData(String volume, String bid, String total){


            mMessages.add(new BuyOrderHistory.Builder(BuyOrderHistory.RECEIVER)
                    .volume(volume).bid(bid).total(total).build());
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mMessages.size() - 1);
            scrollToBottom();


        }

        private void scrollToBottom() {
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        }


        protected Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i(TAG, "disconnected");
                        isConnected = false;
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.string.disconnect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        protected Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.string.error_connect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };


    }
```

Below is my Adapter class:-

```
    public class BuyOrderHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


    ArrayList<BuyOrderHistory> arrayList;
    Context context;
    private int RECEIVER = BuyOrderHistory.RECEIVER;



    public BuyOrderHistoryAdapter(ArrayList<BuyOrderHistory> arrayList,Context context){

        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = null;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (viewType == RECEIVER){

            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_buyorders, parent,false);
            vh = new ReceivedDataHolder(v);


        }


        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder.getItemViewType() == RECEIVER){
((ReceivedDataHolder)holder).volume.setText(arrayList.get(position).getmVolume());
            ((ReceivedDataHolder)holder).bid.setText(arrayList.get(position).getmBid());
            ((ReceivedDataHolder)holder).total.setText(arrayList.get(position).getmTotal());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList == null ? 0 : arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(arrayList.get(position).getmType() == RECEIVER){

        }
        return RECEIVER;
    }

    private class ReceivedDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       public TextView volume, bid, total;

       public ReceivedDataHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           volume = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_buyvolume);
            bid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_buybid);
            total = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_buytotal);
       }
   }
```

Comment: create new instance of adapter once you got data in arraylist from server then set it to recyclerview

Comment: In on attach arraylist is empty

Comment: @VishvaDave please guide me what should i do because of this even in  onConnect method log is also not working  as initially i am just checking whether its getting connected or not.but due to skipping layout i am not even able to see  message from server

Comment: @VishvaDave can you please suggest me changes so i can check whether my code is executing on connect and all methods as i am not even getting Toast for getting connected which is there in onConnect method.

Comment: Once you get successful response from server after that write all this lines. create instance of adapter there (once arraylist have data filled in) and then recyclerview setup lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try :**

```
            mMessages.add(new BuyOrderHistory.Builder(BuyOrderHistory.RECEIVER)
                    .volume(volume).bid(bid).total(total).build());
            mAdapter = new BuyOrderHistoryAdapter(mMessages, getContext());
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mMessages.size() - 1);
            mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mLinearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_buyorder);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Tutorial :

- [tutorial 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644218/data-inside-recyclerview-is-getting-populated-twice-using-socket-io)
- [tutorial 2](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/#)
- [tutorial 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892399/getting-socket-io-response-in-android-client-but-cant-understand-how-to-implem)

Comment: mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_buyorder); how view will come in addData method

Comment: even  mAdapter = new BuyOrderHistoryAdapter(mMessages, context); context is also coming in red

Comment: write getContext() instead context

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri Check updated answer. replace this and any error then let me know

Comment: i have changed that but the issue is with the view  in   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_buyorder);

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri move that line to onCreateView only that line

Comment: still E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri debug it and check whether arraylist have data and it is going to adapter and setting values or not

Comment: now i have update my Code the thing is i first i need to connect to the socket and then i have to emit an event and then i will get data from server which is in onBuyOrderData but i am not even getting connected message in my device

Comment: sorry i am troubling you but i am quite new to these sockets stuff and all

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri you are new to socket but i am not even know anything about that :( I only know about recyclerview process that if we are passing arraylist to adapter then it should be filled not empty. and after that setup adapter with recyclerview

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri now you neeed to find out your way that where you find data by debugging

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892399/getting-socket-io-response-in-android-client-but-cant-understand-how-to-implem

Comment: @HimanshuAgnihotri If my answer solves your problem then please mark this as correct

Answer (score 0):

1) "No adapter attached; skipping layout" is not an error, but rather an info from the `RecyclerView` informing you that there is no adapter at this time. See the `dispatchLayout()` method from the RV [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java)

2) To solve your issue: add an the following method to your **adapter** class:

```
public void add(BuyOrderHistory item){
  arrayList.add(item);
  notifyItemInserted(arrayList.indexOf(item));
}
```

Then call this method on your Adapter instance as soon as you have a `BuyOrderHistory`  object created and all fields set. You could of course re-init and re-set your adapter each time you got new data, I would not recommend that however.